# raster2pgsql unable to append raster to table

Tags: raster, postgis, raster2pgsql

I was successful in loading a raster to a table "raster_files" in the "environment" schema in my gdb. However now I am trying to append the rest of the rasters to that same table.

Using this command:

```sh
raster2pgsql -I -s 26915 -a environment.raster_files -C -F C:/Users/ichth/OneDrive/Documents/Geospatial_Databases/Final_Project/resized_images/img1.tif | psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 -d MSRiver_Restoration
```

But I am getting the error: ERROR: Unable to read raster file:
`environment.raster_files`

Comment: Isn't the usage documented to be `raster2pgsql raster_options_go_here raster_file someschema.sometable > out.sql`? Using option `-a` does not change the order of input and output.